# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error between c# and c in virtual machine

Tags: c#, c, virtual-machine

im making a project where i have a communication between a c# windows forms application and a c application in a virtual machine (vmware). when i try to connect between the two i get an error on both sides every time. i have already disabled my firewall and its still not working.

my C# code:

```
private void ConnectClient(string server, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                Int32 port = 8888;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
            
        }

private void ConnectBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectClient("192.168.80.128", "test");
        }
```

my C code in Virtual Machine:

```
#define PortNumberApp 8888
#define IPadressApp "192.168.137.1"

void checkConnection(int connection_status)
{
 if(connection_status == -1;
 {
  printf("there was an error connecting to the socket\n \n");
 }
 else
 {
  printf("connection succesfull\n \n");
 }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 int network_socketApp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);

 struct sockaddr_in serverApp_adress;
 serverApp_adress.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serverApp_adress.sin_port = htons(PortNumberApp);
 serverApp_adress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPadressApp);

 int connection_statusApp = connect(network_socketApp, (struct sockaddr *)&serverApp_address, sizeof(serverApp_addres));
 checkConnection(connection_statusApp);

 char message[30];
 while(1)
 {
   if(read(network_socketApp, message, sizeof(message)))
   {
     write(network_socketApp, "OK!", sizeof("OK!"));
     bzero(message, sizeof(message));
     read(network_socketApp, message, sizeof(message));
     printf("Message from App: %s\n", message);
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

i turned off my entire firewall which i hoped would fix the problem but this did not solve anything as i still get the same error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.80.128:8888".

Comment: Your both programs look like TCP clients. Server must `bind()` to address, enter to listen mode with `listen()` and `accept()` incoming connections.

Comment: Regarding possible firewall/virtual NAT issues, try to establish connection between host and guest with command line tools, e.g. `netcat` first and check if it works.